# How can I improve my question to get a detailed answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvote-reason, quality-improvement

I have asked a question on SO ([How can I enforce a mouse cursor refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46933200/how-can-i-enforce-a-mouse-cursor-refresh)) and I'm asking myself: Why do people downvote this question and what I could do to improve it.

I think that I got the point in this question, a short description of what should work and what doesn't work with the code part which is affected.

**Do you know what I could do better?** Because I don't know what I did wrong.

<sup>*"I'm not here to complain about those 'bad' downvotes, I'm here to learn being valuable for SO.*"</sup>

Comment: Without knowing anything about that particular domain, the highly upvoted answer by Zarenor might give shed some light into the situation. It implies that your question is based on a "misunderstanding". I've seen many times that such questions are not necessarily well received.

Comment: @yivi but what could I improve to make it clearer? I don't want to have such bad received questions, I want to be a value for SO.

Comment: Again, no I do not know anything about this subject matter. But you already have comments and answers on that particular question that should give you clues about what could be wrong about it.

Comment: And regarding "why do people downvote this question", we can only speculate. Votes are personal, and only the voters know why the cast them one way or another. Mind reading is very expensive and unreliable, so the feature had to be disabled.

Comment: @yivi I have forgot my title, thank you for the help

Comment: There are tens of thousands of questions asking about why a desktop UI application isn't updating, and basically all of them (including yours) are the same.  You didn't do your research, and there's *lots* of readily available information on this topic.

Comment: @Servy sure I researched bevor I wrote this question. None of the solutions had fixed my mouse problem. I searched around 30 min bevor I gave up on google. If someone found a other solution which should fix my problem then he could write it as a comment or not?

Comment: @Hille Since I remember that you were a supporter of idownvotedbecause, and following on Servy's comment; you can now see how a http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ link by any of the voters wouldn't have really helped you.

Comment: But I insist: there are at least a couple comments/answers that should give you hints about why some people might find your question less than stellar.

Comment: @yivi about idownvotedbecou.se, like I wrote, if you insert this link in a nice little text which is **helpful**, then I would appreciate it ;)

Comment: Servy did that, and what you did was argue that you **had** done you research. That's where commenting on votes (even hypothetical votes) get you.

Comment: @yivi as I said, none of those solutions helped me. I'm not here to complain about those 'bad' downvotes, I'm here to learn being valuable for SO.

Comment: The little disclaimer that you added at the top does nothing to show how your situation is different than those other solutions or to show your research into your issue. Personally, I find the question even worse with than unsubstantiated disclaimer than without it.

Comment: To explain Yivi's point, if I had asked a question like, "Who's the current president of the United States?" and prefaced it with, "I know that there are more than enough questions about this out there, but none of those answers help me with my problem?" or if I'd said, "I spent 30 minutes searching for the answer to this question, so it's well researched." do you think that everyone now must consider the question to have been well researched?

Comment: @Servy Now I got the Point of yivi, thanks. I must totally agree. I rewrote the full question, can you two please take a lock on it and tell me if its better than bevor or what else I could improve?

Comment: Historically, there has been two types of people on SO: Those who think it is only for experts, and those who think it is to help others, as long as they did reasonable research into the topic. Add to that the fact that sometimes you don't know what is the right question to ask, especially if you are new to a topic. This is many times overlooked by "coders".

Comment: @Makketronix how is it overlooked? We have duplicates for EXACTLY that. If you post something that still displays good research and a bit of effort on your end, you will likely get an upvoted duplicate question. In any case SO is neither for experts nor is it to help people who provide effort. It's to build a long lasting repository of knowledge. THAT's how it helps people: by providing tools and information someone looking to fix their issue themselves will use. It Isn't to give a copy pasteable code for  the millionth duplicate of an NPE we see.

Comment: @Patrice The point I am highlighting is, although there is wealth of information on stackoverflow, it will not "sink" in the minds of new people, because it is one level above where they are starting. Then the posted question will be a wrong question. Some people answer: "You are trying to ask this: ...", while others bring the downvote hammer. Not saying which is correct. Just highlighting what happens.